# How to update badge in tabhost android from another activity or class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using android-badgeviewer to show the number of notifications in the tab. I have the code something like below.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homepage_x,container, false);


    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("HOME").setIndicator(getTabIndicatorhome(mTabHost.getContext(), "HOME")),
            homepage.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("NOTIFICATIONS").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), "NOTIFICATIONS")),
            notificationfragment.class, null);
    return rootView;

}

private View getTabIndicator(Context context, String title) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    tv.setText(title);
    TextView tv_counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_counter);
    BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(getActivity(), tv_counter);
    badge.setText("1");
    badge.show();
    return view;
}
private View getTabIndicatorhome(Context context, String title) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout_home, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text_home);
    tv.setText(title);
    return view;
}
```

Now i need to update my badge from another activity or class. How do i do it?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use activity/fragment communication documented here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.

Example:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
    OnDataChanged mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnDataChangedListener {
        public void onDataChanged(int numberOfThingsChanged);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnDataChangedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnDataChangedListener");
        }
    }

    // When your data actually changes call back to the tab fragment
    private void somethingChanged() {
       // No need to check if we have a callback, onAttach already did that
       // notif change
       mCallback(27);  // 27 things changed.
    }
}
```

Then in your main tab fragment implement that interface (your class in your question):

```
  public class MyTabFragment implements OnDataChangedListener {
      ...

        @Override
        public void OnDataChangedListener(int numberOfThings) {
          // update your badge here
        }

      ... 
   }
```

Android example has interface defined in one fragment.  If you have multiple tabs that will all get badges I would define the interface in its own class/file.